# access protected class using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

How could I access protected class by means of reflection?
This one does not work:

```
Class.forName("java.awt.AWTInvocationLock");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That class is an inner class of EventQueue so the full path is:

```
    Class.forName("java.awt.EventQueue$1AWTInvocationLock");
```

Comment: I'm just trying not to confuse people who will read later by setting some post as an answer when it is not really is. And usually wote up to ALL usefull notes :)

Comment: While I understand that strategy it's not benefitting you.  If you know the answer you can always answer it yourself, and award that as the answer.  But, your current mode of operating is hurting your stats more than helping the community.  You've only asked 5 questions so maybe asking more will drown out the 2 you didn't accept any answers on.  Just so you know :-)